# links inside Rails3 flash are escaped

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to render a link inside a flash message in Rails 3.  I'm setting the flash message in the controller like this:

```
flash.notice = render_to_string 'shared/message_with_a_link', :layout => nil
```

This works just fine.
But then let's say I already *have* a flash message to render, and I just want to append the message with the link.  I tried switching `=` to `+=`, like so

```
flash.notice += render_to_string 'shared/message_with_a_link', :layout => nil
```

And now the flash div contains both messages, but the link has been escaped, so it shows up as `<a href="google.com">google</a>` instead of [google](http://www.google.com).

Does anyone know why the flash would be escaped in the second case but not the first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.html_safe` on your string.
More info [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/).

Comment: That solves the immediate problem... I'm still curious about why it would be necessary in the second case but not the first

Comment: I tried the same right now, and I don't even have to call .html_safe at all? I'm not using render_to_string, but a plain string. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: maybe the thing that was already in flash.notice wasns't html safe?  if I call .html_safe on both of them then it works, but not if i only call it on one.  oh well.